# How to simulate just one ENTER in command line after executing a JAR file

Tags: linux, bash, jar

I am trying to write a script that executes a JAR file and automatically puts the inputs when prompted.

For now I just want to simulate pressing enter once.

With the following:

echo -en "\n" | java -jar file.jar

it will repeatedly keep hitting enter not just once.

I've tried other variations like just echo | but it stays repeating.

Answer (score 0):

To output a newline just use

```
printf '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should promise your JAR file be executed
2. your JAR file can receive params when it is executed

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
java -jar file.jar << EOF

EOF
```

Note the <kbd>Enter</kbd> at Line#2